# Using ScrollViewReader in SwiftUI how can I highlight the row I have scrolled to?

Tags: swiftui

If I create this simple `ScrollView` containing 100 rows and create a button to scroll to row 60, I would like to highlight that I am at row 60, maybe with a background colour or similar. I cannot figure out how to do this.

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            
            Button("Jump to #60") {
                value.scrollTo(60, anchor: .center)
            }
            ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                Text("Line \(i)")                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible approach - you introduce state for highlighted row, which can modify by needs, including for scroll to

Tested with Xcode 12b5 / iOS 14

```
    @State private var highlighted: Int?
    var body: some View {

        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { value in

                Button("Jump to #60") {
                    value.scrollTo(60, anchor: .center)
                    highlighted = 60
                }
                ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                    Text("Line \(i)")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(i == highlighted ? Color.gray : Color.clear)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way.

Create a function to set a colour if the current index and the scrollTo target are equal.

```
func highlight(index: Int, target: Int) -> Color {
    if  target == index {
        return .black
    } else {
        return .clear
    }
```

Then use it to set background, border etc.

```
              Text("Line \(i)")
                    .border(highlight(index: i, target: 60), width: 5)
```